# PHP white page when uploading too much images

Tags: php, html, image, .htaccess

I got a problem regarding a form I have. It's an image upload form which you can upload images with with a file input. When I try to upload 21 images it doesn't work but when I put 17 images in it it works. The 21 images gives a white page and it uploads images till the 17-18 (it differences).

Now I checked it out and I think, but I'm not sure, it has to do with the internet speed. If I try it on a slow internet speed it gets canceled but else the images get through.

I changed my .htaccess with the following fields:

```
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value memory_limit 1000M
php_value max_file_uploads 100
php_value max_input_time 600
php_value max_execution_time 600
```

Has it to do with the execution or input time? The slow speed actually can actually process for 15 minutes before the white page shows. Or am I forgetting php values I need to set?

Comment: is it sharing hosting or your own resource? Do you have a control under webserver? If not, .htaccess is not always helpful...

Comment: It might be that your server is timing out.. I had the exact same issue once.. you need to specify the max execution time on your control panel of your website hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks I will ask my provider. I have actually a shared VPS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the following to the top of the upload script to see exactly what is causing the failure.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', '81');
```

This "should" show the exact PHP error that is occurring, which will help you determine how to correct it.

I would also MAKE SURE your PHP changes are actually taking effect by checking the result in phpinfo();  Could be that the Apache HTACCESS changes are not overriding the php.ini settings?

Comment: Yes, I see the changes in the phpinfo() appear. So I assume that the changes are actually live. Another user suggested to ask my provider for timing out of the server so I will do that now. Thanks for the info code, I will add that also to check if I get any usual information.